# python error[11001] getaddrinfo while using microphone as source

Tags: python

I fixed errors in my program but it gets stuck at " Listening..."

and doesn't accept my commands is there any issue with 'sapi5'??

and should I try any other tts engine

here is my code :

```
import pyttsx3
import dateTime
import speech_recognition as sr 
import webbrowser
import wikipedia
import os 

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    # print(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour) 
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        print("Good Morning!, sir")
        speak("Good Morning!, sir")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        print("Good Afternoon!, sir")
        speak("Good Afternoon!, sir")
    else:
        print("Good Evening!, sir")
        speak("Good Evening!, sir")
    print("I am Mark. your virtual assistant, please tell me how can I help you? ")      
    speak("I am Mark. your virtual assistant, please tell me how can I help you? ")      
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("am Listining...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("say that again please..")
        return "None"
    return query
if  __name__ == "__main__":
    wishMe()
    while True:        
        query = takeCommand().lower()
     elif 'bye' in query:
            print("good bye, see you soon")
            speak("good bye, see you soon")
            exit()
```

**it dosent take any of my command**
how can i fix it?

Comment: A casual glance of the [source](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/c89856088ad81d81d38be314e3db50905481c5fe/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L623) and documentation for the `listen` method indicated to me that it may be stuck listening.  Try passing a `timeout` to `r.listen` (e.g. `r.listen(source, timeout=10)` to listen for at most 10 seconds) and see if you get something.

Comment: No it didn't work.....